# Spring boot client fails to register Spring boot admin (version 2.x)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am running spring boot application with basic authentication enabled and spring boot admin with UI security enabled .

My spring boot client fails to register to the spring boot admin server . Below are the logs :

```
2018-08-23 15:17:09.676 DEBUG 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created POST request for "http://localhost:9001/instances"
2018-08-23 15:17:09.699 DEBUG 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2018-08-23 15:17:09.724 DEBUG 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [Application(name=spring-boot-application, managementUrl=http://localhost:8001/relay/actuator, healthUrl=http://localhost:8001/relay/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8001/relay)] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@12c0c0b3]
2018-08-23 15:17:09.864 DEBUG 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@5953ec3b8 pairs: {POST /instances HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json}{Content-Type: application/json}{Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_161}{Host: localhost:9001}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 287}
2018-08-23 15:17:10.124 DEBUG 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@126c0bea10 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 403}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-Frame-Options: DENY}{X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block}{Content-Type: text/plain}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2018 09:47:10 GMT}
2018-08-23 15:17:10.128 DEBUG 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:9001/instances" resulted in 403 (null); invoking error handler
2018-08-23 15:17:10.138  WARN 4992 --- [gistrationTask1] d.c.b.a.c.r.ApplicationRegistrator       : Failed to register application as Application(name=spring-boot-application, managementUrl=http://localhost:8001/relay/actuator, healthUrl=http://localhost:8001/relay/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://localhost:8001/relay) at spring-boot-admin ([http://localhost:9001/instances]): 403 null. Further attempts are logged on DEBUG level
```

Below are my webSecurity config class from admin server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class SpringStarterAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringStarterAdminApplication.class, args);
    }


    // Added for spring boot security login ui for admin



        public static class SecuritySecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final String adminContextPath;

        public SecuritySecureConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
            this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
            successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
            successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(adminContextPath + "/");

            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and() 
            .logout().logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and()
            .httpBasic().and() 
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())  
                .ignoringAntMatchers(
                    "/instances",   
                    "/actuator/**"  
                );
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
```

Not sure what is preventing the client to register to admin Server .

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you get any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

The inner configuration class should be annotated with @Configuration too.

It's even better if you refactor it into a separate class.